# XPath difference between two similar path and other questions

Tags: xpath

I've to made some exercices but
I don't really understand the difference between two similar path

I've the tree :

```
<b>
   <t></t> 
   <a>
      <n></n>
      <p></p>
      <p></p>
   </a> 
   <a>
      <n></n>
      <p></p>
   </a> 
   <a></a> 
</b>
```

And we expect that each final tag contain one text node.

I've to explain the difference between //a//text()  and //a/text()

I see that //a//text() return all text nodes and it seems legit,
but why  //a/text() return the last "a node" -> text node ?

Another question : 
why //p[1] return for each "a node", the first "p" child node ?
   -> I've two results

```
<b>
   <t></t> 
   <a>
      <n></n>
      **<p></p>**
      <p></p>
   </a> 
   <a>
      <n></n>
      **<p></p>**
   </a> 
   <a></a> 
</b>
```

Why the answer is not the first "p" node for the whole document ?

Thanks for all !

Comment: I downvoted your question for several reasons: broken input (no text nodes at all?), use of irrelevant tags ([tag:xquery] does not seem related for plain XPath). If you're wondering about different query results, please also post those. If you have some expected output, also post it (does not apply here). I'll gladly revert the downvote if the question is reworked, but as is it definitely is not answerable.

Comment: I still don't see any text nodes in your document. What is the actual input you're querying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Difference between 1: `//a//text()` and 2: `//a/text()`

Let's break it down: `//a` selects all `a` elements, no matter where they are in the document. Suppose you have `/a`, that would select all root `a` elements.

If the `/` path expression comes after another element in an XPath expression, it will select elements directly descending the element before that in the XPath expression (ie child elements).

If the `//` path expression comes after another element in an XPath expression, it will select all elements that are descendant of the previous element, no matter where they are under the previous element.

Applying to your two XPath expressions:

1. `//a//text()`: Select all `a` elements no matter where they are in the document, and for those elements select `text()` no matter where they are under the `a` elements selected.
2. `//a/text()`: Select all `a` elements no matter where they are in the document, and for those elements select any direct descendant `text()`.

> Why `//p[1]` returns for each "a node", the first "p" child node?

Suppose you were to write `//a/p[1]`, this would select the first `p` child element of any `a` element anywhere in the document. By writing `//p[1]` you are omitting an explicit parent element, but the predicate still selects the first child element of any parent the `p` element has.

In this case there are two parent `a` elements, for which the first `p` child element is selected.

---

It would be good to search for a good introduction to XPath on your favorite search engine. I've always found [this one from w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_intro.asp) to be a good one.